# Installing XFCE desktop (package: xubuntu-desktop) alongside GNOME desktop (package: ubuntu-desktop): ubuntu-desktop breaks

Tags: 10.04, installation, gnome, xfce

### The Issue

I'd like to install the XFCE interface alongside the GNOME interface that comes preinstalled with Ubuntu.

However, when I try to install the package `xubuntu-desktop`, I end up with this:

```
[kahless]# aptitude install xubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information      
Initializing package states... Done
Writing extended state information... Done
The following packages are BROKEN:
  ubuntu-desktop 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  a2ps{a} abiword abiword-common{a} abiword-plugin-grammar{a} 
  abiword-plugin-mathview{a} app-install-data-commercial aumix{a} 
  aumix-common{a} catfish exaile exo-utils{a} fortune-mod{a} 
  fortunes-min{a} gigolo gnumeric gnumeric-common{a} gnumeric-doc{a} 
  gtk2-engines-xfce libabiword-2.8{a} libaiksaurus-1.2-0c2a{a} 
  libaiksaurus-1.2-data{a} libaiksaurusgtk-1.2-0c2a{a} libexo-0.3-0{a} 
  libexo-common{a} libgdome2-0{a} libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a{a} 
  libgtkmathview0c2a{a} liblink-grammar4{a} libotr2{a} libots0{a} 
  libpsiconv6{a} librecode0{a} libscim8c2a{a} libsdl1.2debian-alsa 
  libtagc0{a} libthunar-vfs-1-2{a} libwv-1.2-3{a} libxfce4menu-0.1-0{a} 
  libxfce4util-bin{a} libxfce4util-common{a} libxfce4util4{a} 
  libxfcegui4-4{a} libxfconf-0-2{a} libxmlrpc-core-c3{a} 
  link-grammar-dictionaries-en{a} mousepad murrine-themes{a} orage 
  oss-compat{a} pidgin pidgin-data{a} pidgin-libnotify{a} pidgin-otr 
  psutils{a} python-cddb{a} python-mmkeys{a} python-mutagen{a} 
  python-sexy{a} ristretto scim scim-bridge-agent{a} 
  scim-bridge-client-gtk{a} scim-gtk2-immodule{a} scim-modules-socket{a} 
  scim-modules-table{a} scim-tables-additional tango-icon-theme-common 
  thunar thunar-archive-plugin thunar-data{a} thunar-media-tags-plugin 
  thunar-thumbnailers thunar-volman{a} thunderbird ttf-lyx{a} usb-creator 
  xfce-keyboard-shortcuts{a} xfce4-appfinder xfce4-clipman{a} 
  xfce4-clipman-plugin xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-dict 
  xfce4-fsguard-plugin xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-mixer 
  xfce4-mount-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-notes{a} xfce4-notes-plugin 
  xfce4-panel{a} xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-power-manager 
  xfce4-power-manager-data{a} xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin 
  xfce4-screenshooter xfce4-session xfce4-settings{a} 
  xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin xfce4-systemload-plugin xfce4-terminal 
  xfce4-utils{a} xfce4-verve-plugin xfce4-volumed xfce4-weather-plugin 
  xfce4-xkb-plugin xfconf{a} xfdesktop4{a} xfdesktop4-data{a} xfprint4 
  xfswitch-plugin xfwm4{a} xfwm4-themes{a} xscreensaver xubuntu-artwork{a} 
  xubuntu-default-settings xubuntu-desktop xubuntu-docs 
  xubuntu-gdm-theme{a} xubuntu-icon-theme{a} xubuntu-plymouth-theme{a} 
  xubuntu-wallpapers{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio{a} xaw3dg{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 121 newly installed, 2 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 75.7MB of archives. After unpacking 261MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  ubuntu-desktop: Depends: libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio but it is not installable
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Remove the following packages:
ubuntu-desktop

Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
catfish recommends slocate
Score is -81

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

These lines here worry me the most:

```
Remove the following packages:
ubuntu-desktop
```

Is there a way to install the XFCE desktop alongside Gnome without causing ubuntu-desktop to break?

### More Info (1)

Using `apt-get` results in the same issue.

### More Info (2)

Attached are the other solutions that aptitude provides:

Solution 1 was listed above.

Solution 2:
    The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

```
Keep the following packages at their current version:
libsdl1.2debian-alsa [Not Installed]
libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio [1.2.14-4ubuntu1.1 (lucid-updates, now)]

Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
catfish recommends slocate
xubuntu-desktop recommends libsdl1.2debian-alsa
Score is -210

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Solution 3:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Keep the following packages at their current version:
libsdl1.2debian-alsa [Not Installed]

Downgrade the following packages:
libsdl1.2debian [1.2.14-4ubuntu1.1 (lucid-updates, now) -> 1.2.14-4ubuntu1 (lucid)]
libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio [1.2.14-4ubuntu1.1 (lucid-updates, now) -> 1.2.14-4ubuntu1 (lucid)]

Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
catfish recommends slocate
xubuntu-desktop recommends libsdl1.2debian-alsa
Score is -220

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think aptitude is trying to remove ubuntu-desktop because it is broken:

```
"The following packages are BROKEN:
ubuntu-desktop"
```

**1)**
You can go to **System > Administration Synaptic Package Manager** then go to **Edit > Fix broken packages**.

**2)** If "1" fails, then choose "n" to not accept the option of remove ubuntu-desktop.

**3)** To restore the Gnome login manager:

```
gksu gedit /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

and change it's content to `/usr/sbin/gdm`

ps.: if you don't like the gdm xubuntu theme, you can remove it:

```
sudo aptitude remove xubuntu-gdm-theme
```

Regards.

Comment: @desgua: nope, doesn't work.  I think its because of this:   `ubuntu-desktop: Depends: libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio but it is not installable`, and the system is trying to remove `libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio`.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I added the additional 2 solutions given by `aptitude` to the answer under **More Info (2)**

Comment: Option 2 looks like it will work.

Comment: I'm testing option 2 now, i hope everything doesn't implode :/

Comment: Well, that option worked.  @BillThor Last question, how can I restore the Gnome login manager?  I like the GNOME login screen better than the XFCE one.

Comment: I'm glad to help ;-)

Comment: Although, strangely enough, `gdm` was already set as the default display manager.  So I delved into Synaptic, and found that the `xubuntu-gdm-theme` was installed, and I couldn't choose between the themes.  By doing `aptitude remove xubuntu-gdm-theme`, I restored the initial Ubuntu theme for the login manager.  Too bad there's no way for me to choose whichever theme I want to use other than removing other theme's packages :/

Comment: Humm I think "How to choose gdm theme could be a good new question", couldn't it? Anyway I will add this observation to the answer too...

Comment: i'm considering writing a question for that, so I probably will :P